# How to do sound localisation for an Inmoov Robot

Tags: raspberry-pi, servo, sound, robotics, robot

I have to do sound localisation for a humanoid robot. This is my final year project given by our sir but I have no idea how to do it can anyone help me

Comment: Well, the first step is ***google/literature research***: https://www.frontiersin.org/research-topics/21452/sound-source-localisation-in-mobile-robots#articles

Comment: Do you want the robot to be able to locate a sound source, perhaps to orient itself to a talker? Or do you want the robot to be able to use perhaps ultrasonics to locate itself within a room, so it can move about avoiding obstacles? They are different problems requiring different solutions.

Comment: This is **your** final year project. If you literally, truly **have no idea how to do it** then you should demand a refund of your tuition or start a different career path. But I think you **do** have an idea. So tell us as much as you can about the problem and how you would approach it.

Comment: "Sound localization" is "only" a "delay" problem between 2 sensors ... if one locutor speaks. If not, one shall do as "dolphins".

Comment: @Neil_UK it has to orient itself towards the talker...Do you have any direct resources or solutions to how to implement it

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I only know that I have to do it on raspberrypi and microphone sound detection sensors has to detect sound and the servo motor should turn towards the highest intensity of sound from sound sensor... But I don't know how to implement this idea into a code form so that I can try on raspberrypi

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://www.cochlea.eu/son/psychoacoustique/localisation), and [this](https://dcase.community/challenge2020/task-sound-event-localization-and-detection) ...

Theory ...

> **LOCATION IN A HORIZONTAL PLANE**
> Interaural time difference (ITD)
> The difference in arrival time of a sound wave at each ear is an important index for estimating the position of a source in the horizontal plane.
> A sound signal emitted from a localized source S, in a horizontal plane, by an angle α and a distance r from the center of an individual's head will have a different path to travel to reach the right ear (R) and the left ear (L): in our case, the distance SL is greater than SR, the sound will therefore arrive more quickly at the right ear. The differentiated arrival of the sound wave to each ear is called interaural time difference (ITD). When the source is at azimuths 0° or 180°, the ITD will be 0. Conversely, the ITD will be maximum when the source is at azimuths +- 90°, i.e. approximately 0.7ms (for the average size of a human head).
> The ITD is a fundamental index for locating a source emitting waves whose frequency is less than 1500Hz. Above 1500Hz, the ITD becomes ambiguous. However, in the case of complex sounds, the ITD of the envelope (slow modulation) of the high frequencies would be perceived (**interaural envelope difference: IED**).
> **Interaural Intensity Difference (IID)**
> The head tends to oppose the passage of the sound wave; this is also referred to as the head shadow effect. Thus, an interaural intensity difference (IID) appears, which reflects the difference in intensity of the wave reaching each ear. However, this index strongly depends on the frequency of the incident sound. When it is below 1500Hz, the IID is almost non-existent. On the other hand, for frequencies higher than 1500Hz, the IID becomes an effective index.*

One can apply this idea with the "Autocorrelation function".
The delay (or "phase") between the two signals (ears) can be used for "retrieving" axis direction.
Note that there is an "unknown" of 180°. So others sensors are needed (4).